# Learned about circular linked list, but whenever I try to diplay the list, I get Segmentation fault (core dumped). link: https://pastebin.com/0vrgfVpR

Tags: c

Here is the display function

```
void display(){
    temp = tail; //tail points to the last node
    do{
        temp = temp -> next;  //next points the the next node
        printf("%d\t",temp -> data);
    }while(temp != tail);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Did you try running your program using a debugger?

Comment: Segfault is typically the result of accessing memory locations that do not belong to you. Where you get the segfault is usually not where the root cause of the problem is. Any of the variables you access, such as `temp->next` can be invalid. Run your code through a proper debugger and see if any of the variables are referring to unallocated/freed memory locations. If you cannot find it, modify your question to have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide [A Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). From what you've posted, there is no way to tell whether the list is singly-linked or doubly-linked. That's why a MRE is critical for anyone providing any type of concrete answer. If you can edit your question adding a MRE, then you question can be reopened.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you did not include the supporting code to go with this function call, the best guess is that either the "next node" value in your last (tail) node or some "next node" value in the list is null.  Not having your code, I took a bunch of artistic license and built a sample program to utilize your function in the spirit of the project.  Following is the snippet of code to perform a minimal creation of a circular list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *previous;
    struct node *next;
} node_t;

void display(node_t * tail){
    node_t *temp = tail; //tail points to the last node
    printf("Nodes starting at tail->next (should be the head node)\n");
    do{
        temp = temp -> next;  //next points the the next node
        printf("%d\n",temp -> data);
    }while(temp != tail);
}

node_t * create_node()
{
    node_t * work;
    work = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    work->data = 442;
    work->previous = NULL;
    work->next = NULL;
    return work;
}

node_t * add_node(node_t * head, int value)
{
    node_t * work;
    node_t * links;
    work = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    work->data = value;

    links = head;
    while (1)
    {
        if (links->next == NULL || links->next == head)
        {
            break;
        }
        links = links->next;
    }
    links->next = work;
    work->previous = links;
    work->next = head;

    return work;
}

int main()
{
    node_t *head, *tail;        /* Avoid global variables */

    /* Create initial head node */

    head = create_node();

    /* Create a few list entries */

    tail = add_node(head, 832);
    tail = add_node(head, 236);
    tail = add_node(head, 438);
    tail = add_node(head, 784);
    tail = add_node(head, 182);

    display(tail);

    return 0;
}
```

Following are some of the highlights.

- First off, reviewing your function you evidently had defined your "tail" and "temp" pointer variables as global variables.  Global variables are usually something you want to shy away from as they sometimes can get modified somewhere in the program that is not obvious.  So those were revised to be defined either in the "main" function or in the function where they are being used.
- Although not probably necessary, a "previous" node pointer was added to the prototype linked list structure just to make it convenient if ever there needs to be a reason to traverse back through a linked list.
- The linked list pointers are utilized when calling functions for the linked lists as well as being returned when new nodes are created, again to better control their creation and to avoid or minimize the need for global variables.

Testing out your function (with the tweaks to the variable definitions) provides an output in the spirit of your circular linked list.

```
@Una:~/C_Programs/Console/PrintLinks/bin/Release$ ./PrintLinks 
Nodes starting at tail->next (should be the head node)
442
832
236
438
784
182
```

Dissect and analyze the functions and structure to see if this meets your project requirement.